# Find by multiple conditions in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I want to search a table with multiple conditions in Rails. I am using Active record and rails version 3.1.0.

I have Movies object, and want to achieve the equivalent of the following in rails:

```
Select * from Movies where rating = 'R' OR rating = 'PG'
```

I tried the following but it does not work

```
@filtered = Movies.find(:all, :conditions => { :rating => 'R', :rating => 'PG' })
```

Can you please provide help to write an equivalent of SQL query mentioned above.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One way would be to build an "IN" condition with:

```
 @filtered = Movie.where(:rating => ['R', 'PG']).all
```

EDIT: I changed your class to "Movie" from "Movies".  I assume that's what you will want.

Comment: @Mischa - Very true, but that would of course depend on where and how one is using the statement, and I agree in most cases it's not necessary. For this answer, I wanted to explicitly return the resulting array and not an ActiveRecord::Relation object to avoid any possible confusion. Thanks for pointing that out though!

Comment: I just think it looks strange to call `all` when you *don't* want all. If you are only doing it to return an array instead of an `ActiveRecord::Relation` it would IMO be clearer to just call `to_a` instead.

Answer (score 10):

In Rail 4, find with multiple conditions for example consider find `Profile` with `first_name` and `last_name`

```
Profile.find_by first_name: 'stack', last_name: 'flow'
```

Finds the first record matching the specified conditions. There is no implied ordering so if order matters, you should specify it yourself.
If no record is found, returns nil

```
Profile.find_by! first_name: 'stack', last_name: 'flow'
```

Like find_by, except that if no record is found, raises an ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound error.

For more information read  [Rails Finder Method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find_by)

[1](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find_by): http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find_byIn Rail 4, find with multiple conditions for example consider find `Profile` with `first_name` and `last_name`

```
Profile.find_by first_name: 'stack', last_name: 'flow'
```

Finds the first record matching the specified conditions. There is no implied ordering so if order matters, you should specify it yourself.
If no record is found, returns nil

```
Profile.find_by! first_name: 'stack', last_name: 'flow'
```

Like find_by, except that if no record is found, raises an ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound error.

For more information read  [Rails Finder Method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find_by)

Answer (score 5):

i guess that would be

```
Movie.where("rating = ? OR rating = ?", 'R', 'PG')
```

have a look at the guides for more info: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#conditions

i would recommend using an `IN` statement instead.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it using:

```
Movie.where(:rating => ['R','PG'])
```